# How to mark code in GitHub bug report?

Tags: github

When creating a bug report on GitHub, is there any way one can easily mark a block of code as a code? I.e. it would indent the marked block by four spaces. Ideally something similar to **`{}`** icon on StackExchange. Is there something like that? Indenting every single row can of copy-pasted code can be pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three back ticks ``` on the line above and below the code create a "fenced code block" in GitHub.

You can also do syntax highlighting, ex ```ruby

Documentation here:

https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown#fenced-code-blocks